# dividing a div in to more then 1 columns

Tags: php, html, css, forms, wordpress

I am using [Contact Forms 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) to create contact form in wordpress installation. the form created is located [here](http://www.sproutwellnesscenter.com/test-form/)

Contact Form extension is free, flexible and easy to use..but issue is, whatever number of fields a form contains, it always creates only one div and thus page length goes long ( see my form created)

I dig up the code and ended in `contact-form-7\includes\classes.php`. the code responsible for generating html of the form is

/* Generating Form HTML */

```
function form_html() {
    global $wpcf7;

    $form = '<div class="wpcf7" id="' . $this->unit_tag . '">';

    $url = wpcf7_get_request_uri();

    if ( $frag = strstr( $url, '#' ) )
        $url = substr( $url, 0, -strlen( $frag ) );

    $url .= '#' . $this->unit_tag;

    $url = apply_filters( 'wpcf7_form_action_url', $url );

    $class = 'wpcf7-form';

    if ( $this->is_posted() ) {
        if ( empty( $wpcf7->result['valid'] ) )
            $class .= ' invalid';
        elseif ( ! empty( $wpcf7->result['spam'] ) )
            $class .= ' spam';
        elseif ( ! empty( $wpcf7->result['mail_sent'] ) )
            $class .= ' sent';
        else
            $class .= ' failed';
    }

    $class = apply_filters( 'wpcf7_form_class_attr', $class );

    $enctype = apply_filters( 'wpcf7_form_enctype', '' );

    $form .= '<form action="' . esc_url_raw( $url ) . '" method="post"'
        . ' class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '"' . $enctype . '>' . "\n";

    $form .= $this->form_hidden_fields();

    $form .= $this->form_elements();

    if ( ! $this->responses_count )
        $form .= $this->form_response_output();

    $form .= '</form>';

    $form .= '</div>';

    return $form;
}
```

I am looking for some way so that I can

- divide `<div class="wpcf7"` into 3 divs containing approximately same
  No of fields
- or inserting `<div>` in between <`form action="`somewhere so that I
  can expand my form horizontally in approximately (not totally) equal
  `div's`

My other form, whose format I want to follow is located [here](http://www.sproutwellnesscenter.com/new-client-form/)

**upadate:**

- I am using Eunoia theme and short codes like [one_third first] to
  apply the CSS and page structure are not working, to me, it make
  sense as the plugin use the same '[ tag ]' structure
- I tried adding `div` elements in form code, but still nothing
  happens, although in source code of page, these `div` tag appears...

**An other Question rose in mind**
My theme codes are like `[some theme code]` they dont work and simply output on the page...any suggestion I can make use of it??

can somebody suggest me a way out to do this? some rough ideas, some guide line, so that I can try to code that...

thanks..

Comment: I suggest learning PHP/HTML/CSS and rewriting/editing the Code or hiring a developer to do it.

Comment: @Stefan I can try for editing, but I just need some outlines, some idea to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your fields into a zero indexed array, this will do the trick ([phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/996-fzy)):

```
$fields=array('F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8');
$fieldCount=count($fields);
$column=0;
$columnCount=3;
//All columns have this many fields
$perColumn=floor($fieldCount/$columnCount);
//This many fields left over (to be distributed over the first columns)
$extras=$fieldCount - $perColumn*$columnCount;
$i=0; //All fields iterator
$j=0; //Column fields iterator
$columnFieldCount=$perColumn;
if($extras>$column)$columnFieldCount++;
echo '
<style>.column{float:left; width:25%;}</style>
<div class="column">';
for($i=0; $i<$fieldCount;$i++)
{
    echo '
<p>'.$fields[$i].'</p>';
    $j++;
    if($j>=$columnFieldCount)
    {
        $j=0;
        $column++;
        $columnFieldCount=$perColumn;
        if($extras>$column)$columnFieldCount++;
        echo '
</div><div class="column">';
    }
}
echo '
</div>';
```

Comment: should I add the above code in HTML genaration function in between '$form .= $this->form_hidden_fields();' and '$form .= '</form>';' right?

Comment: Yes, and change `echo '...` to `$form.='...` - also fix the style: this is a crude example.

Comment: thanks buddy, thanks for this help, I am going to try it..also, how can I use my theme short code in it like '[my theme short code]' any idea?

Comment: @NewBee sorry, you lost me there. I'm not familiar with the specific tool/framework.

Comment: thanks for this help...extension is looking quite interesting to me, and I hope I will learn a few more things from it...trying to this short code too now ..thanks again for your help

Comment: I'm looking a bit closer at your code. I think the correct place to put this is in your form_elements() function.